# Format date in generic list based on todays date (WPF, DataGrid, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, date, generics, datagrid

I'd like to format the date in a generic `List<T>`. If the current item's date in the list is equal to today's date, the date should be formatted like this:

```
12.12.2015 12:34:56 //dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS
```

if not then the date should be formatted like this:

```
12.12.2015 //dd.MM.yyyy
```

The code looks something like this:

```
private List<T> ConvertDate(List<T> inList)
{
    foreach (var item in inList)
    {
        if (item.Date == DateTime.Now)
            item.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        else
            item.Date.ToString("dd.MMMM.yyyy");
    }
    return inList;
}
```

I display this in a DataGrid using C# and EF6:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = ConvertDate(initList);
```

How do I update the formatted date in the list?

EDIT:

Here's my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

This is how I fill it with data:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    List<Error> initList = context.Error.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Take(500).ToList();
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = ConvertDate(initList);
}
```

Comment: better you can use a IValueConverter to achieve this refer link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think you need to use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now` when you compare based only their date value. And there is no `SS` specifier, it should be `ss` instead. Format specifiers are case sensitive. You need to use `mm` for minutes part, `MM` specifier is for months. Would be better to use `if(item.Date == DateTime.Today) item.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: please post your datagrid , @DrKoch  is ok only if are binding to the item itself within a column , if you bind to Item.Date it will not work . 

post your DataGrid please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will nead a [converter](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to achive that:

XAML:

```
<Window //...
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
    //...
>

<Window.Resources>
    <c:DateToCustomDate x:Key="converter" />
    //...
</Window.Resources>
```

C#:

```
namespace ExceptionLogViewer
{
    public class DateToCustomDate : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                var date = (DateTime)value;
                if (date == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    return string.Format("{0:d} {0:t}", date);
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Format("{0:d}", date);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }


        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an overload of `ToString()` to your item class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.Date.Date == DateTime.Today) // ignore TimeOfDay
        return this.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS");

    return this.Date.ToString("dd.MMMM.yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Dont I have to give some params? Like `List<T> inList` and where doI call the method?

Comment: If the datagrid wants to display an item it uses its `ToString()` method as default.

Comment: I get this error: `'Test.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'ExceptionLogViewer.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: In your `ConvertDate` code you access the `Date` property of each item, so I assumed each item has such a property. Are you sure you added ToString() to each **item** class?

Comment: Indeed, but I fill the list generic with an LinQ-statement and there is no such method nor variable in my code

Comment: No, I didnt add ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a Converter or a calculated property in your model.

With a property :

CS :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<Item>();

            list.Add(new Item{ Date =  DateTime.Now});
            list.Add(new Item { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });

            return list;
        }
    }

}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string DisplayDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now.Date == Date.Date ? Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS") : Date.ToString("dd.MMMM.yyyy"); }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayDate, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

With a converter :

CS:

```
      public class DateToDateFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime) value;
        return DateTime.Now.Date == date.Date ? date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS") : date.ToString("dd.MMMM.yyyy");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource dateFormatConverter}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```